# Using laser scattering beams instead detectors in Double Slit Experiment?

Tags: electrons, scattering, double-slit-experiment, particle-detectors

In the Double Slit Experiment for electrons could be possible the use of an appropriate laser pointer at one slit aiming up so when an electron passes through that distinct slit it get scattered up so its picture on the screen will show up in the upper part. The question that arises: will the electron path probability collapse?

Answer (score 0):

If by any means you determine a slit the electron goes through, then the interference pattern will go away. So in this case there will be no interference pattern, as you will be able to associate a slit with each detection event.

Speaking a little more abstractly / loosely, by detecting the slit the particle goes through, the wave function is now being described as having a single source from that slit as opposed to two sources (one for each slit). As such, you will lose any double-slit interference pattern.

Comment: Is the electron behaviour comparable in a variant with a boat making waves which when reflected from the shore(slit) eventually disturb the boat movement?